# Finding the distance from a point to a curve.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How can I find the distance from $(0,0,0)$ to the curve $$C=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3};\frac{x^2}{4}+y^2+\frac{z^2}{4}=1,x+y+z=1\}$$

Comment: After calculating the intersection curve, I don't know how to follow

Comment: You should include that in your work

Comment: Have you tried using the distance formula?

Comment: Do you know about Lagrange multipliers?

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Consider these two functions of the three coordinates.

$$f=\frac{x^2}{4}+y^2+\frac{z^2}{4}-1$$
$$g=x+y+z-1$$

Then the tangent $\hat{t}$ to the curve $C$ must be perpendicular to both $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ (why?). In other words 
$$\hat{t} \propto \nabla f \times \nabla g$$

At the point $p$ on the curve C that is closest to the origin, you get that this tangent vector must be perpendicular to the vector $(x,y,z)$ (why?)

Solve this simultaneously with $f=g=0$ and you get two points on the ellipsoid where these are all met. One is the nearest to the origin and one is the farthest. Pick the smaller distance of these (smallest norm).  [Edited, thanks to comments below]

Comment: I like your method, but there are actually four solutions to this system of equations.

Comment: @amd Thanks, you are right. Let me update. OP is good to go if there are a finite number of points to check in the end

Comment: I understand the first part, and I see why the tangent vector has to be perpendicular to the vector $\overrightarrow{OP}$ but why is this vector $(x,y,z)$? Also what do you mean by solving $f=g=0$? Solving it as a system of equations?@amd, why are there four soultions instead of 2? graphically I see that the only points the tangent vector will be perpendicular to the vector distance will be the closest and farthest point of said curve. Maybe I'm asking too many questions, anyway thank you for your time.

Comment: If P, the point you solve for, is the point (x,y,z), and O is (0,0,0) then the vector OP is just (x,y,z), no? f(P)=0 because the point P lies on the ellipse. g(P)=0 because lies on the plane. The *equation* you get from $t\perpto OP$ has 2 extra roots. But only two of them lie on the curve C (ie. Only 2, satisfy f=g=0. One is nearest, one is the farthest). The others are spurious. I was able to compute the points explicitly. When you compute it, you’ll see the the closest point is at an obvious location. (Confirmed by the calc). Farthest is the one that needs the calc to be found at all.

Comment: @Jdoeoeo If the answer is not one you can accept, please ask more questions.